# Unary notation representation in Turing Machine

Tags: turing-machines, automata

What can be a good convention to represent positive and negative integers in unary notation on a Turing machine? I want to design a Turing machine which acts as a subtractor.So should I partition the integer range to represent positive and negative integers in unary notation or is there some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A reasonable convention would be to take any enumeration of the integers and use it. For example, this enumeration
$$
0,1,-1,2,-2,3,-3,\ldots
$$
corresponds to this encoding:
$$
\begin{align*}
0 &\to \epsilon \\
1 &\to 1 \\
-1 &\to 11 \\
2 &\to 111 \\
-2 &\to 1111 \\
3 &\to 11111 \\
-3 &\to 111111
\end{align*}
$$